# Creation of dataset for SRCNN - Tensorflow : Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create a dataset containing high resolution images and their corresponding low resolution for a super resolution convolutionnal neural network

Starting from the high resolution, I've created 2 lists (1 Ground truth and 1 low resolution) of images with same dimension.
From https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/ we can see that the input data should be a Numpy array so I also transformed it.

```
ds_lr = [] #Low resolution list
ds_gt = [] #High resolution list
#Degradation of GT image to lower resolution
for filename in os.listdir(filepath_gt):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(filepath_gt,filename))
    if img is not None:
        #Keep x percent of the pixel of the original picture
        width = int(img.shape[1] * config.SCALE_PERCENT  / 100)
        height = int(img.shape[0] * config.SCALE_PERCENT  / 100)
        
        # dsize
        dsize = (width, height)
        
        # Lower resolution Image
        output = cv2.resize(img, dsize, interpolation=None)
        
        #Resize low resolution image
        width_resize = int(output.shape[1]  / (config.SCALE_PERCENT/ 100))
        height_resize = int(output.shape[0] /(config.SCALE_PERCENT / 100))
        
        if width_resize != img.shape[1]:
            width_resize += 1
        if height_resize != img.shape[0]:
            height_resize += 1
            
        d_resize = (width_resize, height_resize)
        img_lr_resize = cv2.resize(output, d_resize)

        ds_lr.append(img_lr_resize/255)
        ds_gt.append(img/255)

#Transforming the list in numpy array
ds_lr_arr = np.asarray(ds_lr, dtype = object)
ds_gt_arr = np.asarray(ds_gt, dtype = object)
```

When trying to use this to train my neural network, I encounter the following error: **Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).**
Even while using `tf.convert_to_tensor`.

```
#Train CNN
history = srcnn.fit(
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(ds_lr),
    y = tf.convert_to_tensor(ds_gt),
    #x = ds_lr,
    #y = ds_gt,
    batch_size = config.BATCH_SIZE, 
    epochs = config.EPOCH,
    callbacks=[cp_callback],
    validation_split = 0.2
    )
```

I am wondering if this could be linked to the fact that each image of the list has a different size.

Do you know a solution or alternative to this problem.

Comment: Why are you specifying `dtype=object`?  Tensor creation errors like this often seem to be caused by arrays with object dtype, and differing sub-array lengths.  `tensor` apparently works best with "rectangular" arrays with an numeric dtype.

Comment: Without specifying `dtype=object`, I get a warning message : *VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.*
I don't really understand this message

Comment: Do you understand the concept of `shape` or size of arrays?  You are trying to make an array from a list of arrays, some of which differ in shape.  That's what the warning is saying.  When you specify `object`, that silences the warning, but doesn't change the fact that the resulting array is "ragged".  For cases like this `tensorflow` doesn't give you a warning, it raises an error.

Comment: So it's not possible to have a dataset with images of different size?

Comment: tensorflow basics should discuss what kinds of datasets are allowed.  I usually help people with the `numpy` end of these problems, and haven't studied (or used) the TF end.